# Forcing a ligature in "lowercase" small caps

Tags: typography, small-caps, ligatures, kerning

Adobe Garamond Pro has a very nice swash Q ligature, but it only works for uppercase Q. Since "lowercase" small caps are still based on the uppercase letters, I would like to use this Q for all small caps. Is this possible?

Example in XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[%
   Contextuals=Alternate,
   Style=Alternate,
   Ligatures=Rare,
   SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=7}]%
{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Quack quack}   

\end{document}
```

[image: Small caps ligatures]

Comment: Does the font have a small-caps version of the alternate? You can only use it if it is there. (You don't seem to be faking small-caps, which is good, so I'm not sure why you think they are 'based on' the upper case.)

Comment: @cfr The font doesn't seem to provide this ligature, unfortunately. I guess what I'm asking is whether there is a reasonably good way to fake this ligature from the uppercase Q for all small caps Qs.

Comment: No. If you only fake the Q, it will not match the other small caps. If you fake all small caps, it will match, but be much poorer quality than using the optical small caps. Faked small caps are always inferior to optical small caps. Personally, I try extremely hard to avoid them: if I need small caps, I use a font which has them.

Comment: Look at the two Qs in your image. Notice that the smaller one is not simply a scaled down version of the larger one. The thinnest parts of the letter are relatively thicker, for example. This means that the small caps will look as black as the upper case rather than being greyed out. When small caps are faked, you don't make them as small as real small caps to avoid their becoming too grey. But it is still a compromise and not a satisfactory one: the small caps will still be less black than upper case and a little oversized relative to lower case. A fake Q will look obviously terrible.

Comment: @cfr I just had a go and faking the Q isn't THAT terrible in my opinion (http://i.imgur.com/QV9BHdD.png), but I would still want to avoid doing that. Perhaps this ligature for Garamond does exist somewhere. Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Off-topic, but I hope the font isn't calling the swash-Q a ligature. A ligature is when two letters are 'bound' together (hence the name) to create one (in computer terms) glyph. The most common one being `&`, which is really just `e`+`t` (`et` = Latin for 'and'), but there were others like `ﬆ`; and the various 'f' ones (e.g. `ﬀ`) are quite common today.

Comment: @jon You are right, I was imprecise. I think some typefaces have "Qu" with a swash Q as a ligature, but in this case it's just a swash Q glyph.

Comment: @jon In traditional TeX fonts, `ligature` has a significantly  broader meaning and swashes may be implemented as ligatures in some cases, even when no other letter is involved. For example, end-of-word swashes can be implemented in this way (and I know of no other way to implement them). Technically, two characters are involved, but they certainly need not be two letters or even two glyphs - one may be a boundary marker, for example. Of course, traditional fonts aren't relevant here, but it can certainly make sense to say that `Q swash is implemented as a ligature in this font`.

Comment: If you feel like buying yourself an expensive gift (just think of it as doing your part for the economy), Adobe’s Garamond Premier Pro Opticals has the long-tailed Q in small caps.  So does EB Garamond.

Comment: It definitely looks inferior to the line above with the genuine small caps Q. That was my point. Opinions differ on whether it is acceptable to fake small caps for fonts which don't have them - I'm against, but others differ - but (partially) faking them for fonts which do ... that is beyond the pale, in my opinion. I think it will (almost) always give a poorer result.

Comment: @cfr -- I suppose you can slot a 'swash Q' in under any category you want in an OTF font, but there are certainly [better choices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typographic_features#Ligation_and_alternate_forms_features_intended_for_all_scripts) for such features. I wasn't saying that you can't implement a swashed character so that it is activated by (say) `+hlig` (or even `+liga`), just that you shouldn't. What is the definition of ligature in TeX? *TeX by Topic* doesn't seem to suggest anything different than the standard meaning.

Comment: @jon I agree. All I meant was that in TeX fonts, you don't have those options. So various things are implemented as ligatures which are not typographically ligatures. I'm talking about what you put into the TFM/VF files. Not just (typographic) ligatures get implemented (in TeX fonts) as ligatures, if that makes sense. No idea if there's a definition.

Comment: @cfr -- I see what you mean. I was thinking only of OTF not traditional TeX fonts because of the `fontspec` package.

Comment: I've added the "kerning" tag, as the posting's main issue appears to be more about kerning than about ligatures *per se*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using XeLaTeX, is there a reason for not using the free-of-charge `EB Garamond` font? Its main text features are very similar to `Adobe Garamond`. Moreover, it does have a very nice "swash-y" "Q" in both (regular) uppercase and small-caps.

[image]

Aside: If you use LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX, you'll need to provide the option `Contextuals=Alternate` to `fontspec` in order to get the "swash-y" Q.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
Quack \textsc{quack}   
\end{document}
```